# T-SQL split a row with 3 sets of data with different effective dates into 3 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a file (not my design!) coming from a HR system with a number of fields in it, and different sets of fields have different Effective dates. I don't know of the 3 fields which will be the older or newer of the dates.  I've simplified the number of fields, but the principle holds:

```
rec# EmpNmbr Store  StorEffDate Part  PT Eff        EmpGrp  EmpGrp
                                Time   Date                 Eff Date                                
1    90122   T202   03/07/2018   X    26/07/2018    Summary 01/07/2018    
2    90122   LR86   13/08/2018        20/07/2018    Regular 14/08/2018    
3    90122   T707   11/10/2018   X    03/09/2018    Summary 12/09/2018
```

For example I need to split up record 1 so that there are 3 records:

Effective dates and data:

01/07/2018 to 02/07/2018 with EmpGrp = Summary and Parttime and Store are null (I will obtain the actual data from what is currently active on 01/07/2018).

```
03/07/2018 to 25/07/2018 with Store = T202, EmpGrp = Summary, and Parttime null.    
26/07/2018 to 01/01/3000 with Store = T202, EmpGrp = Summary, and Parttime=X
```

Then from record 2, I would need:

```
20/07/2018 to 12/08/2018  T202 (from record above), Parttime=''and EmpGrp = Summary    
13/08/2018 to 13/08/2018 LR86, Parttime=''and EmpGrp = Summary    
14/08/2018 to 01/01/3000 LR86, Parttime=''and EmpGrp = Regular
```

etc

Hopefully this is clear, but what I need to be able to do is to split each record into 3, and sequence them in date order by one of the 3 date effective fields and associate the individual data fields with it's date effective field.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like a problem for https://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/01/unpivot-a-table-using-cross-apply/

Comment: Keeping it simple..what's wrong with UNION of 3 Selects..that should do it

Comment: Hi DIWP - I've tried a union query but that just gives me the same 3 rows 3 times - I still have the problem of unpicking the 3 sets of data to work out what sequence they should be in. I can't sort on any specific fields as any of the 3 date fields could be in any sequence.

Comment: Hi user1443098. I've been looking at different types of query like unions and cross joins. And even started to look at storing the data into a temporary table so that I can programmatically iterate through it (somehow). I did try looking at some pivot/unpivot examples but couldn't find any that looked close to what I am trying to do, and as I've not used that functionality before I wasn't sure if it could do it. But I'll take a more detailed look at that link - on the face of it it cold be useful, thanks.

Comment: @nycoy, can u post what u tried with UNION

Comment: Hi DIWP - I've tried a few things, but have been updating what I did based on your suggestion that it could work. I think it might be workable.

My current SQL is


order by recnum,date 

I get results as follows:

Comment: Hi DIWP - I've tried a few things, but have been updating what I did based on your suggestion that it could work. I think it might be workable.
SQL is

SELECT recnum,[Personnum], 'Lab' as datatype
 ,[StoreID] as field1
  ,convert(varchar(10),[LabAccEffDate],103) as date
  from Z_EMD_MASTER 
union all 
SELECT recnum,[Personnum], 'PT'
      ,[PartTimeInd]
      ,convert(varchar(10),[PartTimeEffDate],103)
  from Z_EMD_MASTER 
union all
SELECT recnum,[Personnum], 'EG'
 ,[EmployeeGroup]
 ,convert(varchar(10),[EmployeeGroupEffDate],103) 
  from Z_EMD_MASTER 
   order by recnum

Comment: I get results as follows:

rec Personnum datatype field1 date
1 00090122 Lab T202 03/07/2018
1 00090122 PT X 26/07/2018
1 00090122 EG Summary 01/07/2018
2 00090122 EG Regular 14/08/2018
2 00090122 PT  20/07/2018
2 00090122 Lab LR86 13/08/2018
3 00090122 Lab T707 11/10/2018
3 00090122 PT X 03/09/2018
3 00090122 EG Summary 12/09/2018

This looks promising. I need to work out a way to get ALL the data fields into the row so that the 2nd row 1 for example knows that it needs to use T202 and the 3rd row 1 knows it needs to use T202 AND X.

Answer (score 0):

nycoy, you should explain your logic of "splitting" a row into multiple (2 or 3). Without knowing the logic, based on the provided sample and expected result, i "guess" this might be what you want. If it is not, it should gives you the lead to change to your actual logic

```
-- Sample Table
declare @sample table
(
    rec#        int,
    EmpNmbr     int,
    Store       varchar(5),
    StorEffDate date,
    PartTime    char(1),
    PTEffDate   date,
    EmpGrp      varchar(10),
    EmpGrpEffDate   date
)

-- Sample Data
insert into @sample 
select  1,    90122,   'T202',   '2018-07-03',   'X',    '2018-07-26',    'Summary', '2018-07-01'   union all
select  2,    90122,   'LR86',   '2018-08-13',    null,  '2018-07-20',    'Regular', '2018-08-14'   

-- The Query
select  rec#, n.EffDate, n.ExpDate, n.Store, n.EmpGrp, n.PartTime
from    @sample s
    cross apply
    (
        select  EffDate = s.StorEffDate, ExpDate = dateadd(day, -1, s.PTEffDate), s.Store, s.EmpGrp, PartTime = null
        where   StorEffDate < PTEffDate

        union all

        select  top 1 EffDate = s.PTEffDate, ExpDate = dateadd(day, -1, s.StorEffDate), x.Store, x.EmpGrp, PartTime = null
        from    @sample x
        where   s.PTEffDate < s.StorEffDate
        and x.StorEffDate   < s.StorEffDate
        order by x.StorEffDate desc

        union all

        select  top 1 EffDate = s.StorEffDate, ExpDate = s.StorEffDate, s.Store, x.EmpGrp, s.PartTime
        from    @sample x
        where   s.StorEffDate   < s.EmpGrpEffDate
        and x.StorEffDate   < s.StorEffDate
        order by x.StorEffDate desc

        union all

        select  EffDate = s.PTEffDate, ExpDate = '01/01/3000', s.Store, s.EmpGrp, s.PartTime
        where   s.PTEffDate > s.EmpGrpEffDate

        union all

        select  EffDate = s.EmpGrpEffDate, ExpDate = '01/01/3000', s.Store, s.EmpGrp, s.PartTime
        where   s.PTEffDate < s.EmpGrpEffDate
    ) n
order by rec#, EffDate
```

Comment: Hi Squirrel. Apologies, my post hasn't formatted well- there is an expected record dated 01/07/2018 to 02/07/2018 in the output that is missing from your suggestion.

The logic is that there are 3 pairs of data on each record (data field and effective date): 

Store and Store effective date, 
Part time (is blank or X) and Part time effective date and 
Emp Group and Emp Group effective date. 

Each pair of fields needs to be output onto a new record in the sequence of those dates. So on any given incoming record, any of those 3 fields could be first, second or third chronologically.

Comment: On the first record in this sample file, assuming it is an existing employee, then the Emp group is the oldest date, so for that first generated record, effective 01/07/2018, I would need to get the existing data from the database for the Store and Part time fields valid as at 01/07/2018. For the record effective date 03/07/2018 I would get the current data from the database for Part time field. I'm ok to to add the logic to get this data, so those fields can be output as NULL

Comment: It is possible that 2 of the dates may be equal, in which case instead of outputting 3 records from the one incoming record, we'd only output 2 records, and if all 3 dates were the same we'd only output the one record. Or to put it another way, there should be N output rows based on the number N of unique effective dates on the incoming record. 

I hope this helps to clarify ?

Comment: there are 3 `effective date` in your table. Where is the corresponding `expiry date` ?

Comment: Hi Squirrel - there isn't an expiry date. It is assumed to be the day before the next chronological Effective date. So in the first record, the first derived record is effective from 01/07/2018 to 02/07/2018 because the StoreEffectivedate is 03/07/2018. For the 3rd effective ate chronologically, the expiration date is 01/01/3000. 
So the 3 pairs of records derived from the first incoming record 

1    90122   T202   03/07/2018   X    26/07/2018    Summary 01/07/2018 

from here would have dates
01/07/2018-02/07/2018
03/07/2018-25/07/2018
26/07/2018-01/01/3000